# how to check which forward secrecy cipher is enabled in tomcat 6.0.28 while I use TLSv1.0 protocol?

Tags: ssl, openssl, tomcat6

I am using tomcat 6.0.28 and using TLSv1.0 ssl protocol only. I have configured ciphers as

> ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"

I want to check which are all forward cipher is enabled by using openssl.
Please help me in this case

Comment: Some reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy ...ensure you're using only ciphers that support forward secrecy.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/q/351114/126632